# python json schema check definition of field

Tags: python, jsonschema

I'm using Python to validate json against a json schema (Draft 4).  jsonschema is working nicely for basic validation, but I'd like to add additional checks (outside of jsonschema) for specific subschemas (defined under "definitions" keyword). To do that I'd like pull all fields implementing a particular subschema from an instance being checked.

e.g. if i have the schema

```
{ "definitions": {
    "fu": {
         "type": "object",
     ...
},
...
 "properties":   {
    "P1": {
      "items": { "$ref": "'#/definitions/fu"},
      "type": "array"
  },
    "P2": { "$ref": "'#/definitions/fu" }
  }
    "P3": { "type": "string" } 
}
```

I'd like to pull all instances of a field "/definitions/fu"

So, from

```
{
   "P1": ...,
   "P2": ...,
   "p3" :...,
}
```

I should get the list of fu objects from P1, the fu object from P2, nothing
from P3.

I can't work out how to do this, or if this is possible using the main python libraries: jsonschema or json_schema_validator. Any suggestions?

Comment: Please post your code.

Comment: I could post code showing how I'm successfully constructing and using a jsonschema validator.  But that doesn't seem relevant.  The question is about whether methods exist on jsonschema classes (or other Python libs) that allow me to 'type' instances according to the schema.